# Send complex object from JS to SignalR not working

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, signalr

I'm trying to send data from my front-end to my back-end but the model binding part isn't working properly.

Data looks like this:

```
public class RequestData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("emails")]
    public Emails[] Emails { get; set; }
}

public class Emails
{
    [JsonPropertyName("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("ip")]
    public string Ip { get; set; }
}
```

```
public async Task Start(RequestData data)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Id: {Context.ConnectionId}, website: {data.Website}");
    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Start", "Accepted....");
}
```

If I call this method, I get the error:

```
Failed to invoke 'start' due to an error on the server.
InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked
```

What I'm sending from my front end:

```
{"website":"Teststring..","emails":[{"id":1,"email":"test@live.nl","ip":"127.0.0.1:5000"}]}
```

However, if I do it like this:

```
public async Task Start(string data)
{
    var converted = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RequestData>(data);
    System.Console.WriteLine($"Id: {Context.ConnectionId}, website: {data}");
    await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Start", "Accepted");
}
```

It gets deserialized correctly, so I don't get what is going wrong when I try to put the class as the parameter.

[image]

// Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR(r => 
    {
        r.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<RequestHub>("/hub");
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

// Client

```
<button onClick={() => {
  const data = JSON.stringify({
    website: broadcast.website,
    emails: broadcast.emails
  })
  hubConnection.connection.invoke(BroadcastOptions.Start, data)}}>
Start</button>
```

Comment: There should be an error with more details on the server-side. Check out the output window for more info and please share it in your question.

Comment: I updated the error message

Comment: Can you also share the client code and the `Startup` configuration?

Comment: You are sending a string indeed. Try sending the object instead from the client-side.

Comment: Hmm you are right.. Thanks